# How to restore the surfaceView after onClicked action?

Tags: java, android

I want to restore the content from the GameView Surface after i clicked to return the Game.  "Play again" Button can you help me?

This is the code for the **GameView.java**

```
public void nullify() {
    // Set all variables to null. You will be recreating them in the
    // constructor.
    paint = null;
    lives = 0;
    enemies = null;
    boom = null;
    bosses = null;
    canvas = null;
    player = null;

    envi = null;
    spikes= null;
    paint = null;


    level = 0;
    score = 0;




}
```

This redirect to another Class that will show the score

```
public void gameOver(){   
        //playerDeadFall();
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GameOverDialog.class);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

And then I want to reset the values in the GameView
I´m using this to redirect to GameActivity that initialize the Game.

```
 startActivity(new Intent(this, GameActivity.class));
```

The problem is that when i clicked in the restart button (GameOverDialog) show the score 0 but don't play the game.

Answer (score 0):

i'm going to take a guess out of the blue and say 
try to change the first parameter in the new intent to 
the activity.this

startActivity(new Intent(GameOverActivity.this, GameActivity.class));

Comment: No. I´m using finish() only